# YAML syntax error while parsing a flow sequence

Tags: jinja2

Error - in "", line 2, column 11 did not find expected ','

I am passing a list of lists to the jinja but jinja is not accepting the data format i.e list of lists and giving out errors.

Below is the list of lists that i am passing

x = ["[Account:12345, Key:TAG, Value:1]", "[Account:23456, Key:TAG, Value:]", "[Account:34567, Key:TAG, Value:2]", "[Account:45678, Key:TAG, Value:3]", "[Account:56789, Key:TAG, Value:4]", "[Account:67890, Key:TAG, Value:5]", "[Account:78901, Key:TAG, Value:6]", "[Account:89012, Key:TAG, Value:7]"]

Any help/advice as to what data format i should pass ? I need to loop through this list and get values for Account, Key and Value for every iteration.

Comment: There is no value (i.e. no number after the `:`) for the `Value` field in the second data set.